# How to make a decorated border in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I wanna make a decorated border as in the image in scrollable widget
[image]

Comment: This image using complex shape, you can use ` CustomPaint/clipPath` to create it. Can you include what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images dimension is `473 × 670`. Corner decoration size `115 x 115`. So you can use the centerSlice property to stretch your image according to your needs. Just like this...

```
Image.asset(
  "images/decorated_image.png",
  height: 1000, // device or widget height
  width: 350, // device or widget height
  centerSlice: const Rect.fromLTRB(115, 115, 358, 555),
)
```

Now you can use stack or any other of your prefered method to put this behind your scrollable list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Stack:

```
Stack(
    children: [
       Image(), // your border image
       Container(margin: EdgeInsets.all(12)) // other widgets inside border
    ]
)
```